# Split columns once a group of numbers is repeated

Tags: matlab, data-structures, data-processing

I need help with data processing. I have data columns (force and displacement) for a piston-like mechanism. The data output has the values for 3 strokes which is initial height, bottom, back to initial height (1 stroke) then 2 more strokes. I need help splitting the columns into 3, force and displacement for each stroke. Which makes it harder is that there is some error in the force sensor,  so the second time the piston goes back to initial height, it is not the exact same a the as the initial position.

This is what I have so far.

```
TestData= csvread(fileName, 1, 0);
%add height of piston stop
AdjHeight= TestData(:,2)+ height;
%Concatenate new column of the adjusted heights with 2 columns of raw
%data
NewPistonData=horzcat(TestData,AdjHeight);
%column headers

% Locate the zeros in the 4th column  
index = find(NewPistonData(:,1)==0);
```

Picture of simplified data example, actual data is in the magnitude of hundreds of points per sec:

[image: picture of simplified data example, actual data is in the magnitude of hundreds of points per sec]

In the code line 
    index = find(NewPistonData(:,1)==100); 
I get a column of where I there is 100, but I am stuck in the logic. How do I tell matlab to split columns every time one stroke has been performed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [edit] the question accordingly. The main thing lacking here is "*What's the question?*", you haven't asked one. You wrote a description of what the program needs to do and showed some code, but note that SO is not a free code-writing service. Please elaborate on where you are stuck, what is not working etc.

Comment: Instead of a picture, please provide that as text instead

Comment: Right, I need advice.
In the code line
    index = find(NewPistonData(:,1)==100);
I get the colums of where I there are hundreds, but I am stuck in the logic. How do I tell matlab to split columns everytime one stroke has been performed.

Comment: If the displacement is return to the earlier position (3.8 according to the picture) then one stroke is performed. Am I right?

Comment: You could find the first index in each run of decreasing values. The first value in this run, by definition, will be the max displacement of the piston that cycle. Use `diff( displacement )` to find the differences.